# Localizing Post ID Causes Wordpress Error

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

In my functions.php file I have the function:

```
function add_my_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'extra-script',
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/script.js', 
        array('jquery') 
    );
    wp_localize_script( 'extra-script', 'my_ajaxurl', admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) );
    wp_localize_script('extra-script', 'my_postid', get_the_ID());
    wp_localize_script('extra-script', 'nonce', array( 'nonce' => wp_create_nonce('ajax-nonce') ) );
}
```

In particular, the line `wp_localize_script('extra-script', 'my_postid', get_the_ID());` causes Wordpress to display this error on the front end of the website:

`Cannot use a scalar value as an array in /home/customer/www/[domain]/public_html/wp-includes/class.wp-scripts.php on line 492`

For reference, that refers to:

```
foreach ( (array) $l10n as $key => $value ) {
            if ( ! is_scalar( $value ) ) {
                continue;
            }

            $l10n[ $key ] = html_entity_decode( (string) $value, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8' );
        }
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Post IDs are numbers not strings, so what exactly are you trying to localise? The problem is there in the error message - `wp_localize_script` expects an array but you are not passing an array into it. If you check the parameter list for `wp_localize_script` you'll see which parameter should be an array, then fix the value your passing in everyehere it is wrong (hint: the problem is in 2 of your calls to wp_localize_script).

Comment: Ahh, I see now. Changed it to an array and it worked like a charm. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is as @FluffyKitten put it: Post IDs are numbers not strings, so what exactly are you trying to localise? The problem is there in the error message - wp_localize_script expects an array but you are not passing an array into it. If you check the parameter list for wp_localize_script you'll see which parameter should be an array, then fix the value your passing in everyehere it is wrong.

I changed to `wp_localize_script('extra-script', 'my_postid', array ( get_the_ID() ) );` and it fixed the issue.